# How to get the current height of a BottomSheetDialogFragment programmatically? Or are there any default values for the different states?

Tags: android

I want to change a view size based on the current size of the BottomSheetDialogFragment programmatically, but I don't know how to get or calculate it. I need this information in the `onStateChanged` callback.

Answer (score 0):

On sliding of BottomSheetDialogFragment you can get the height by a little calculation using `locationOnScreen` of the BottomSheetDialogFragment.

> view.getLocationOnScreen(int[] outLocation): Computes the coordinates of this view on
> the screen. The argument must be an array of two integers. After the
> method returns, the array contains the x and y location in that order.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                         //your code here                      
                        } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                         //your code here        
                        }
                    }
    
                    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
    
                           var locationOnScreen: IntArray = intArrayOf(0, 0)
                           bottomSheet.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen)
                
                           // coordinates of bottomsheet when sliding up/down
                           val (x, y) = locationOnScreen
                


                    }
                })
```